# Open Windows Phone 7 App from URL

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to launch my WP7 application from the phone's browser and pass some arguments.  For example, the following url would be a link on an html page.  Clicking the link would start my application.  iPhone and Android both have these capabilites by the name of 'url schemes'.

```
appName://my.arguments.here
```

How can I accomplish this on WP7?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jim, I just want to understand your question before asking another one in the forum... the application is actually installed on your device? or clicking on the HTML page you actually download the application, installing it and than launching it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no support for "url schemes" or custom URL handlers that will allow you to handle these requests from within your application.

Comment: What about windows mango?is the above function is still not available in mango?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to integrate with the search application, which can [provide deep linking into your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286420%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). It also appears that YouTube has some kind of way of doing it, as the mobile version of their site will jump to the app for playback of videos.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the protocol activation feature of Windows Store apps - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx