# launch an app from a URL on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, launching-application

I know that on the iPhone you can register a URL prefix such as myapp://blah which, when opened in safari, will open up your application.

Is there anything like this for Windows Phone 7?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918566/open-windows-phone-7-app-from-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not, applications can only be launched by the user from the application list or home screen. I suspect that the hooks are there in the operating system because the YouTube application is launched when attempting to view a video on the YouTube website from the browser and the user is prompted to install the app if they haven't already got it installed. But unfortunately, this approach isn't publicly available.

Comment: @Derek Lakin is the above function (launch application from a link) available in windows phone mango?

Answer (score 0):

You may give **Receive Push Notifications in an Application for Windows Phone** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402556%28v=VS.92%29.aspx a try.