# Launch an app from within browser within Windows Mango Browser

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, switching

I'm trying to do what is simple in iOS, redirect from the browser to my app (I am authenticating via a website which then loads the url that switches back to my app via appreferencename:/) in Mango.

Is there a way to switch to an app from a browser via a link?

Thanks!

Comment: Because I don't know the official name here is an example of doing it in iOS: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, unfortunately. You are able to link to a marketplace page, but that's only useful if you want to download or update an app.

[Open Windows Phone 7 App from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918566/open-windows-phone-7-app-from-url)